# .ForEach (Javascript) and callbacks

Tags: javascript

So I am working on some precourse work, and hitting a snag on how exactly this code needs to be written.

Given an array called names, the requirment is to use the forEach method, with a callback as the only argument, console log each item in the array.

So my code is spitting out the entire array instead of each item.

My code :

```
function logToconsole(){
console.log(names);
}
names.forEach(logToconsole);
```

link to assignment on repl.it https://repl.it/student/submissions/8911013

Comment: The callback itself must accept at least one parameter. The system will call the function once per element in the array.

Comment: `function logToconsole(name){console.log(name);}`

Comment: thanks, added the parameter to the function I was trying to call back and that fixed my issue. 

code fixed :
    function logToconsole(names){
    console.log(names);
    }
    names.forEach(logToconsole);

Comment: Since the parameter represents a single element, you should really call it `name`

Comment: I can't call it names. Its given. I didnt write that part.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you write your callback function as an anonymous function (a function not named and declared inline) taking "name" as argument?

```js
names = ["Me", "You", "I"]

names.forEach(name => console.log(name));
```

Note that:

- This only works because `names` is iterable;
- The argument `name` could be named anything else and it would still work.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the first parameter from `.forEach` to your function to the `console.log`

```js
var names = ['foo', 'bar'];

function log(name) {
  console.log(name)
}

names.forEach(log)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `forEach` method accepts a callback. The callback accepts a single parameter. The callback will repeatedly be called with each element of the array passed as the parameter.

Essentially, the callback should define what must be done with a single element of the array. `forEach` will handle the rest.

```
function logToconsole(name) {
    console.log(name);
}

names.forEach(logToconsole);
```

Generally:

```
function callback(element) { 
    // perform operation on the element 
}
```

```
array.forEach(callback);
```

- `callback(array[0]);`
- `callback(array[1]);`
- `callback(array[2]);`
- …

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with foreach and you want to uderstand how does it work this must be a easy way to implement it.

```
var arrayList =[1,2,3,4]
```

> for each item inside of the array console log item

```
arrayList.forEach(x=>console.log(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript forEach**

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
numbers.forEach(number => {
    console.log(number)
})
```

**JavaScript Callback function. Look like a forEach**

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
function usingCallbackLookLike_forEach(numbers,callback) {
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        callback(numbers[i])
    }
}
function printFn(number) {
    console.log(number)
}
usingCallbackLookLike_forEach(numbers, printFn)
```